# How to understand equivalent of iOS closures/callback in Android

Tags: java, android, callback, closures

I'm coming from iOS dev and want to know if I'm implementing closures in Android correctly.

This is my iOS code I want to replicate:

```
func playVideoAtCell(_ cellNumber: Int) {

    if (currentlyPlayingVideo) {return}

    getDownloadURL(cellNumber) { (url) in
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
        self.avPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoItemFinished(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayer?.currentItem)

        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }
}


func getDownloadURL (_ cellNumber: Int, callback: @escaping (URL) -> ()) {
    let mediaID = mediaIntroQueueList[cellNumber]["mediaID"] as? String

    Constants.storageMediaRef.child("\(mediaID!)").downloadURL(completion: { (URL, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.showVideoErrorAlert()
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }

        }
        if let downloadURL = URL {
            callback (downloadURL)
        }
    })
}
```

I made an interface in Java:

```
public interface MeetActivityInterface {
    public void downloadURLCompleted(Uri url);
}
```

and this is my java code in the activity:

```
private void playVideoAtCell(int cellNumber){

    getDownloadURL(cellNumber, new MeetActivityInterface() {
        @Override
        public void downloadURLCompleted(Uri url) {
            // play video with url
        }
    });
}

private void getDownloadURL(int cellNumber, final MeetActivityInterface completion) {
    String mediaID = mediaIntroQueueList.get(cellNumber).getMediaID();

    // firebase storage
    Constants.storageMediaRef.child(mediaID).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadURL)
        {
            completion.downloadURLCompleted(downloadURL);
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track? I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, small nitpick-  closures aren't a feature of iOS.  They're a feature of the ObjectiveC and Swift languages.  They're also a feature of a lot of other languages... just not Java.  In Java the way to replicate them is like you've seen-  you create an interface with the functions you require.  Then you pass in an instance of that interface.

What you're doing is creating an anonymous class that implements those interfaces and passing it in.  That's a common way of doing things, and frequently used if the code it needs is small, the interface is 1 or 2 functions, and there's no reuse.  Another way of doing it is to actually write a normal class that implements the interface and pass an instance of that in.  That technique is generally done if you're going to reuse the same implementation in multiple places.

Comment: Ok thanks, I read your answer and took a look at the code again and after studying the java code for a while I think I get the logic flow. One q:  Can you explain what "anonymous class" is? Do I use that? 2nd Q: if I have closures in many different classes, doesn't that mean I will have tons of interface files? Doesn't that get a bit unorganized/unwieldy?

Comment: So when you type MeetActivityInterface(){} what you're doing is defining a new class that implements the MeetActivityInterface interface.  The code in between {} is the implementation of the class-  just like  a normal implementation.  This is called an anonymous class, because you didn't give it a name.  You're then creating a new instance of it (with the new keyword).  And its being passed in as a parameter to the function.  The function you're calling just sees it as an object and can call functions on it as needed, just like with any other parameter.